# The *.efi.signed kernel does not boot, how do I remove it? (linux mint 17)

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

In the course of trying to solve a separate issue, I ran commands to install 'linux-image-generic' and 'linux-signed-image-generic', which I believe installed a new kernel image. I did this without thinking.

Now, when I try to boot, there is a kernel panic and I have to go into grub->old kernels->3.13.0-117-generic, which works. The kernel that does not work, and is now the default for grub, is 3.13.0-117-generic-efi-signed. How do I go about removing this kernel? I'm trying to be careful so as to not nuke the working ones. It is probably unwise to just sudo rm the vmlinuz...efi.signed file from /boot?

Answer (score 0):

I  have solved the problem.  I looked at the apt-get history in /var/log/apt/history.log and then sudo apt-get remove linux-signed-image-3.13.0-117-generic:amd64.  Just look for the signed version and remove it.